# Is it better to create a class that contains only two int or use a matrix?

Tags: java, object, matrix

For example if I have a class "Item" that hasn't no method, with two attributes (price and number), is it better to use an object of this class, or rather use a matrix with two rows, and in the columns all the elements of the shop?
My question is very general, but I mean in terms of speed and ease of use.

Comment: What is clearer and safer? `int price = items.get(0).getPrice()`, or `int price = ((int[]) matrix[1])[0]`?

Comment: Explain your question little bit more. What you are trying to build ?

Comment: I think the first

Answer (score 1):

In a statically typed language like Java, the general pattern is that you create classes for each data object or "DTO", even if the class doesn't have any logic.  So while I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "matrix", I think you should probably just create the Item class.